# Drop down menu in dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to have an assistance on to how I can perform a drop down menu in the said code. The code I have right now is made by another programmer, so when I tried to add a drop down menu style in CSS, it either floats atop of the page or disappears completely. Here are the codes or the said NavBar.

```css
/* CSS Document */

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  display: block;
  color: #800000;
}
ul.submenu li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.navClass li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Holder {
  width: 980px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}
#Header {
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url(../assets/ntma.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}
#NavBar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(13, 13, 13);
}
#Content {
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
#ContentLeft {
  width: 280px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-top: 11px;
}
#PageHeading {
  height: auto;
  padding: 11px;
}
#ContentRight {
  width: 680px;
  float: right;
}
#Footer {
  height: 100px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #665;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  #665;
}
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.StyleTxtField {
  border: 1px solid #665;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Holder">
  <div id="Header"></div>
  <div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>Save</li>
          <li>Update</li>
          <li>Delete</li>
          <li>Report</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="Content">
    <div id="PageHeading">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

You need to hide `submenu` by default and then, show it while hover on main nav's `li`, and in html put `submenu` into `li` not in `ul`

```css
/* CSS Document */

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  display: block;
  color: #800000;
}
ul.submenu {
  display: none;
}
ul.submenu li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#NavBar li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Holder {
  width: 980px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}
#NavBar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(13, 13, 13);
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>Save</li>
          <li>Update</li>
          <li>Delete</li>
          <li>Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's alot for helping me. Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the updated code

```css
nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 position:relative;
}
nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li:hover {
 background-color: rgb(242,242,242);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 display: block;
 color: #800000;
}

.navClass li:hover .submenu {
 opacity: 1;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#Holder {
 width: 980px;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 21px;
 margin-bottom: 21px;
}
#Header {
 height: 70px;
 background-image: url(../assets/ntma.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
#NavBar {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: rgb(13,13,13);
 
}
#Content {
 height: auto;
 clear: both;
 overflow: auto;
}
#ContentLeft {
 width: 280px;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 11px;
 padding-top: 11px;
}
#PageHeading {
 height: auto;
 padding: 11px;
}
#ContentRight {
 width: 680px;
 float: right;
}
#Footer {
 height: 100px;
}
h1 {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #665;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 #665;
}
h6 {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.StyleTxtField {
 border: 1px solid #665;
 border-radius: 6px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 35px;
}
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
 left:0;
 display:none;
}
.submenu li {
 display:block;
 float:none;
 padding:10px 0;
}
nav ul li:hover .submenu {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"> </div>
<div id="NavBar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Save</li>
        <li>Update</li>
        <li>Delete</li>
        <li>Report</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div id="PageHeading">
```

Comment: Thanks a great bunch Naila! Worked like a charm.